# If $\mathcal{P}(X)$ is finite then $X$ is a finite set.

Tags: set-theory

We can find the proof that [if $X$ is finite, then the $\mathcal{P} (X)$ is finite.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1511790/power-set-of-a-finite-set-is-finite-proof-no-cardinality-of-power-set)

I'm trying to see the other implication, without using cardinality, i.e.

$$ \text{If the power set, } \mathcal{P}(X) \text{, is finite, then  } X\text{ is finite.} $$
I'd appreciate a hint to this question.

Help?

Comment: If $X$ is infinite, then $\mathcal{P}(X)$ contains each element of $X$ as a set and thus is infinite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: The map $i:X\rightarrow P(X)$ defined by $i(x)=\{x\}$ is injective, and a subset of a finite set is finite.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

Suppose on the contrary that $X$ is infinite. Consider the singletons.