# Prove that $ \{0,1\}^{|A|} $ is finite

Tags: set-theory

If I want to prove that a set $ \{0,1\}^{|A|} $ is finite for $ A$  finite set in a rigorous formal way, induction is innevitable?

because my idea was to claim that by definition of $ |A^{B}| $, it follows that $ |\{0,1\}^{|A|}|=2^{n}\in\mathbb{N} $ and therefore $ 2^{n}<\aleph_{0} $.

Is this proof wrong? I have to use induction in order to prove this claim?

If someone with experience of checking exams could tell me if he would accept this proof, this would be very helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof seems correct. But if you want to use induction... go ahead, use induction on the size of $A$.

Assume $ \{0,1\}^{|A|} $ is finite and is of size M. What is then the size of the set $ \{0,1\}^{|B|} $ where B is any set which has 1 element more than $A$?

Comment: Actually I do not want to use induction. But my proffesor gave me 3/10 for this proof, and claimed that there is no other way to prove it rather than induction over the size of A. But I just cant understand why. $ 2^{|A|} $ is a natural number. every natural number is smaller than $ \aleph_{0} $ and therefore the set is finite

Comment: Then you may want to argue with the professor. Then you will understand if there's a flaw in your proof or not. Maybe you assumed something which is obvious but not really proven. But he cannot just say: "this is the only way" without explaining why. You should argue with him and find out.

Comment: I did, the answer I got was "this is an argument over the natural numbers, you have to prove by induction that it holds for any natural number, saying $ 2^{n} $ is finite is just assuming what you were suppose to prove "